# Can't find method in module

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust and trying to figure out why I can't call a method from a module I have written. The code is very simple as it's a learning exercise and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370120/right-way-to-have-function-pointers-in-struct) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994509/how-do-i-call-a-function-through-a-member-variable) but I still don't know what the problem is. I have also tried using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075846/attempting-to-use-self-in-a-rust-program) almost exactly however the error persists.

The code for main.rs and helper.rs are below.

main.rs:

```
mod helpers;

fn main() {
    let h = helpers::new("TestString");
    println!("{}", h.get_name().to_string());
    helpers::test_func();
}
```

helpers.rs

```
struct Helper{
    name: String
}

impl Helper {
    pub fn new(name: &String) -> Helper {
        let helper = Helper{ name: name.to_string()};
        return helper;
    }
}

impl Helper {
    pub fn get_name(&self) -> &String {
        return &self.name;
    }
}

pub fn test_func(){
    println!("test_func was called.");
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `new` in module `helpers`
 --> src/main.rs:4:30
  |
4 |     let h = helpers::new("TestString");
  |                              ^^^ not found in `helpers`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I know the file is being read because if you commend out lines 4 & 5 from main.rs and just run `helpers::test_func()` it works fine however I don't know why it can't find the new method.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing is the `Helper` struct needs to be exposed from the module. You can do this with the `pub` keyword.

```
pub struct Helper { ...
```

The other thing is that `helpers` is the name of the module, but the `new` method is associated with the `Helper` struct.
You can import the struct with

```
mod helpers;
use helpers::Helper;
```

and then call it with

```
Helper::new(&String::from(""))
```

side note:
You can change the parameter type on `new` from `&String` to `&str`to avoid having to make a new String object and saving a pointless copy.

```
pub fn new(name: &str) -> Helper {
    Helper{ 
        name: name.to_string()
    }
}
```

then call it with

```
Helper::new("")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is constructor call. When calling constructors in rust you can use this syntax:

```rust
let h = Helper{ name: "TestString".to_string() };
```

Also you need to use `to_string` method to convert `&str` to `String`.

Comment: But why can't it find the "new" method?

Comment: If you want you can use it too. But you need to specify struct like: 

Helper::new. 

And also you need to import helpers like: 

mod helpers;
use helpers::Helper;